# SQL Sort based on Count

Tags: sql-server, sorting, t-sql, count

I am trying to edit by comment scrolling page auto load. Right now the SQL query is as such:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[C2_Comments_Viewable] 
    @Viewable INT,
    @C2_ID BIGINT,
    @PageNo INT
AS
WITH LatestComments
AS (
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [DateAdded] ASC ) AS RowDuplicate,     
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [DateAdded] ASC ) AS Row,
        [CommentID],
        [C2_ID],
        [Comment],
        [DateAdded],
        [Viewable]
    FROM C2_Comments
    WHERE [C2_ID] = @C2_ID
    )
SELECT 
    RowDuplicate, 
    Row, 
    CommentID, 
    [C2_ID],
    [Comment],
    [DateAdded],
    [Viewable]
FROM 
    LatestComments
WHERE 
    RowDuplicate BETWEEN (@PageNo - 1) * 100 + 1 AND @PageNo * 100
ORDER BY Row DESC
```

While this works, I am trying to change the sort from DESC to ASC if the number of comments return is < 101.

```
    Case when Count < 101 Then ASC Else DESC End
```

Just can't seem to get it.

---

With Gordon's Help:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[C2_Comments_Viewable] 
    @Viewable INT,
    @C2_ID BIGINT,
    @PageNo INT
AS
WITH LatestComments
AS (
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [DateAdded] **DESC** ) AS RowDuplicate,     
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [DateAdded] ASC ) AS Row,
        [CommentID],
        [C2_ID],
        [Comment],
        [DateAdded],
        [Viewable]
    FROM C2_Comments
    WHERE [C2_ID] = @C2_ID
    )
SELECT 
    RowDuplicate, 
    Row, 
    CommentID, 
    [C2_ID],
    [Comment],
    [DateAdded],
    [Viewable]
FROM 
    LatestComments
WHERE 
    RowDuplicate BETWEEN (@PageNo - 1) * 20 + 1 AND @PageNo * 20
**ORDER BY (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER () < 20 THEN Row END) ASC, Row DESC**
```

DESCPage1
20 > 6

DESCPage2
1 > 5 **Here is my problem, page2 is ASC**

ASC

1 > 20 **Pages not needed thru this order**

What is wrong?

Comment: If your procedure is only performing a single `SELECT` statement please consider changing it to a table-valued function so you can take advantage of function composition. Also consider using the `OFFSET` keyword to perform paging instead of having to compute `ROW_NUMBER()` yourself - it will greatly simplify your query and improve performance.

Comment: thanks for the reply @dai. i have to get things to work before i can even think about improving performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using two separate keys:

```
order by (case when count(*) over () < 101 then row end) ASC,
         row DESC
```

Comment: I am getting this error: ***Column 'LatestComments.RowDuplicate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*** Count was just my psuedo. I tried Group BY the Keys but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had someone else help me with this one. A new @count declaration, and 2 case statements are being used. Everything working now.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[C2_Comments_Viewable] 
    @Viewable INT,
    @C2_ID BIGINT,
    @PageNo INT
AS    
**declare @count as int
set @count = (select count(*) from  C2_Comments
    WHERE [C2_ID] = @C2_ID);**    
WITH LatestComments
AS (
    SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [DateAdded] DESC ) AS RowDuplicate,     
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY [DateAdded] ASC ) AS Row,
        [CommentID],
        [C2_ID],
        [Comment],
        [DateAdded],
        [Viewable]
    FROM C2_Comments
    WHERE [C2_ID] = @C2_ID
    )
SELECT 
    RowDuplicate, 
    Row, 
    CommentID, 
    [C2_ID],
    [Comment],
    [DateAdded],
    [Viewable]
FROM 
    LatestComments
WHERE 
    RowDuplicate BETWEEN (@PageNo - 1) * 100 + 1 AND @PageNo * 100
**ORDER BY CASE WHEN @count < 100 THEN Row END ASC,
        CASE WHEN @count >= 100 THEN Row END DESC**
```

I hope this helps someone else!